# What should I do to avoid excessive SELECTs for roles when working with Spring Security?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

Look at what Hibernate does

```
Hibernate: select a1_0.user_id,a1_1.id,a1_1.role from user_role a1_0 join roles a1_1 on a1_1.id=a1_0.role_id where a1_0.user_id=?
Hibernate: select a1_0.user_id,a1_1.id,a1_1.role from user_role a1_0 join roles a1_1 on a1_1.id=a1_0.role_id where a1_0.user_id=?
Hibernate: select a1_0.user_id,a1_1.id,a1_1.role from user_role a1_0 join roles a1_1 on a1_1.id=a1_0.role_id where a1_0.user_id=?
Hibernate: select a1_0.user_id,a1_1.id,a1_1.role from user_role a1_0 join roles a1_1 on a1_1.id=a1_0.role_id where a1_0.user_id=?
Hibernate: select a1_0.user_id,a1_1.id,a1_1.role from user_role a1_0 join roles a1_1 on a1_1.id=a1_0.role_id where a1_0.user_id=?
```

It makes a separate query for *each* user to get their roles. I would like to avoid it as it looks like a performance killer. I believe there's a way to make Hibernate execute only *one* query for all users to get their roles in one go

As I understand it, the problem has to do with the way my Spring Security is configured

```java
@Configuration
@Import(WebMvcConfig.class)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    private static final String USERS_BY_USERNAME_QUERY = """
            SELECT username, password, enabled
            FROM users where username = ?
            """;

    private static final String AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY = """
            SELECT users.username, roles.role
            FROM user_role
            JOIN users ON user_role.user_id = users.id
            JOIN roles ON user_role.role_id = roles.id
            WHERE users.username = ?
            """;

    public WebSecurityConfig(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("USER")
                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin()
                .successHandler(successHandler())
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
        userDetailsManager.setUsersByUsernameQuery(USERS_BY_USERNAME_QUERY);
        userDetailsManager.setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery(AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY);

        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsManager);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        return (httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) ->
                httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/");
    }
}
```

**What should I do to avoid excessive SELECTs for roles when working with Spring Security?**

My entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String department;
    @Column
    private int salary;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private byte age;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    private byte enabledByte;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Role> authorities;
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String authority;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<User> userList;
```

If you want, you may use [my schema.sql and data.sql files](https://dbfiddle.uk/LOFupilp) for a quick setup. It will create the tables and fill them with sample rows. I think it would be best not to post the scripts directly here to avoid unnecessary clutter

**What I tried:**

1. Setting the fetch type to `EAGER`

```java
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Role> authorities;
```

`SELECT`s were still present

2. Using a `@Query` annotation in my repository and pass a native query that returns roles too

```java
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query(value = """
SELECT users.id, users.username, users.password, users.name,
users.last_name, users.department, users.salary, users.age,
users.email, users.enabled, roles.role
FROM user_role
JOIN users ON user_role.user_id = users.id
JOIN roles ON user_role.role_id = roles.id
WHERE username != :username
""", nativeQuery = true)
    List<User> findAllExceptLoggedUser(String username);
```

Result:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: pp.spring_bootstrap.models.User.authorities: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I want to stress that `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` was still in my `User` class. If I change it to `LAZY`, same effect

Comment: you can use JdbcTemplate, which doesn't use Hibernate/Jpa at all. Still, trying to fetch all the records only makes sense for very small tables.

Comment: Please note that the question is in bold. I mention `LazyInitializatonException` only to tell you what was the result of one of my attempts to address the issue. I never asked how I can avoid that exception (not here, at least). That's why I believe it doesn't make it unfocused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSQL's `JOIN FETCH`es help in this kind of situation

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurityConfig
public class WebSecurityConfig {
// ...
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> {
            User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
            if (user == null) {
                String msg = String.format("No user with username %s is found in the database", username);
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(msg);
            }
            return user;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
```

```java
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query(value = """
            SELECT u
            FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.authorities
            WHERE u.username != :username
            """)
    List<User> findAllExceptLoggedUser(String username);

    @Query(value = """
            SELECT u
            FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.authorities
            WHERE u.username = :username
            """)
    User findByUsername(String username);
```

In the console, you may see something like

```
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.age,a1_0.user_id,a1_1.id,a1_1.role,u1_0.department,u1_0.email,u1_0.enabled,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.name,u1_0.password,u1_0.salary,u1_0.username from users u1_0 left join (user_role a1_0 join roles a1_1 on a1_1.id=a1_0.role_id) on u1_0.id=a1_0.user_id where u1_0.username=?
```